# using namspace std; or std:: (Something) which one is good practice and why?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

In this two code which one is good practice for doing some project?
I'm used to using "using namespace std;" is there any problem to use this?
or i use scope resolution operator?

**code 1:**

```
#include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
  cout<<"Hello world"<<endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

---

**code 2:**

```
  #include<iostream>
  int main()
  {
   std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Also,  `std::endl` is not good practice, as it flushes the buffer, which is a costly operation. Just use `'/n'` for a new line. And you don't have to `return 0;` from main.